# Subprocess opening files

Tags: python

I am using 2 functions written in Python to convert a DLG file to PDB energies:

```
import glob
import os
import subprocess
import numpy as np
from vmd import vmdnumpy as vnp
from vmd import Molecule
from vmd import atomsel

def dlg_to_multiframepdb(fname):
        inputstrings = subprocess.check_output("grep \"DOCKED:\" %s" % fname, shell=True).decode().split("\n")
        output = ""
        for s in inputstrings:
                if s[8:12] == "ATOM" or s[8:12] == "HETA":
                        output += s[8:] + "\n"
                elif s[8:14] == "ENDMDL":
                        output += "ENDMDL\n"
        return output
        
def dlg_to_energy(fname):
        inputstrings = subprocess.check_output("grep \"Estimated\" %s | sed 's/=//g' | awk '{print $8}'" % fname, shell=True).decode().split("\n")[:-1]
        energies = np.array(inputstrings).astype(np.float)
        return energies

# simple code: loop over the directory of DLG filles and convert each file to PDB
pwd = os.getcwd()
dlg= 'dlg'
#set directory to analyse
data = os.path.join(pwd,dlg) 

dirlist = [os.path.basename(p) for p in glob.glob(data + '/*.dlg')]
os.chdir(data)
for dlg_file in dirlist: 
      energies = dlg_to_energy(dlg_file)
      pdb = dlg_to_multiframepdb(dlg_file)
```

Briefly, the first function takes some part from the initial file using shell utility GREP, skipping some unused strings; and the second function - use GREP + SED to take specific strings from the same file and store it as a numpy array. How can the code be further improved?

Comment: [Does this SO question help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44989808/1014587)

Comment: This question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing your code when you already know the current code won't work. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: right, thank you!  my functions just lacked .decode() option! now the code is working and I am waiting for further suggestions regarding its improvement!